# Passing a model to a LayoutView Backbone.Marionette

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, view, model, marionette

I am attempting to pass a **model** to a **LayoutView** so that the particular model attributes can be edited in the view.

In my **ItemView** I have an event that grabs the selected model and assigns it to my global App-

```js
var ItemView = Backbone.Marionette.ItemView.extend({

    template: _.template(ItemTemplate),
    tagName: "tr",
    attributes: function(){
     return {
      "id": this.model.get('id'),
      "class": "tr"
    };
  },
      events: {
        "click #edit" : "edit"
      },

      edit: function() {
        App.EditModel = this.model;
        console.log(App.EditModel);  // <-- prints out the model successfully
        App.trigger('edit');
      }

  })
```

Then, I am using the App.EditModel in my edit view to pass to my template-

```js
var Layout = Backbone.Marionette.LayoutView.extend({

    model: App.EditModel,
    template : _.template(EditTemplate),

    regions : {
   "HomeRegion": "#home"
    }
 });

 return Layout;
});
```

And in the browser I am getting- "Uncaught ReferenceError: firstName is not defined" because the model is not being mapped correctly.

How should I handle this?

Comment: so you set App.EditModel from some instance of ItemView from its model, after click event. Are you sure you instance Layout after these both events and passed proper model to ItemView instance ?

Comment: Yes, the model that is being assigned to `App.EditModel` is the proper one, and If I add an `onShow` function in the `LayoutView`, I can `console.log(App.EditModel)` and print out the model successfully. @Evgeniy

Comment: is 'firstName' being referenced in one of the templates? in which case can you include that code, as well as how the Layout and ItemView are being instantiated?

Comment: @ne8il, yes it is being referenced in the editTemplate. But, the template code isn't relevant to the issue that I'm having. If I change `App.EditModel` to `App.ModelCollection.get(1)`, everything works. Furthermore, if I changed the hard-coded index "1" to a variable that I'm grabbing from the model, it does not work. Example- `App.ModelCollection.get(App.ModelIndex)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When your layout code is first seen the extend function runs taking in all your options, at this point in time I imagine `App.EditModel` does not yet exist and so the model is stored as `undefined`

If you want to pass the model to your `LayoutView` then you should do this when you instantiate it i.e. `new Layout({model: this.model});`

Comment: This is exactly what I needed. I knew that it had to be a timing issue. Thank you, @Quince! Works like a charm!

Comment: quite alright, just as a further note i would always avoid placing models/collections/anything that has already been instantiated,  into the definition of your extended class as if it did exist it would be shared by all instances, which most of the time is not what you want.